# xpath help for xml with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

How do I search for an element hving field='field1' (note-the namespace), this is what I have tried so far..

return value should be the entire fieldPermissions element.

/*[local-name()='Profile']/*[local-name()='fieldPermissions']/*[.='field1'] returns

field1

But I need the parent element (fieldPermissions).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Profile xmlns='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata'>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>field1</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>field2</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
    <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>field3</field>
        <readable>false</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath to compare element text:

```
//*[local-name()="field"][text()="field1"]/..
```

while this ignore the namespace, this one does not (I'm using python lxml):

```
>>> print etree.tostring(tree.xpath('//x:field[text()="field1"]/..', 
                                    namespaces={'x': 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata'})[0], 
                         pretty_print=True)
<fieldPermissions xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>field1</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

Comment: This only returns field element, how do we get the parent (fieldPermissions), this is the output of this xpath query- <field>field1</field>,  What I need back is <fieldPermissions>
        <editable>false</editable>
        <field>field1</field>
        <readable>true</readable>
    </fieldPermissions>